# Openstreetmap & leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap

I am using Django, leaflet and openstreetmap.org to display the map in osm and topo formats. How to display just the map of a country. For example just display the map of Algeria? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can pick an appro[riate zoom level to display all of Algeria and some of its neighboring countries.  However, there's no way to just display one country.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How pick an appro[riate zoom level to display all of Algeria and some of its neighboring countries?

Comment: Here's what I was able to display using the [OpenStreetMap website](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=6/28.094/7.661).  The zoom in and out buttons are on the upper right.

Answer (score 2):

This trick can achieve what you need.
You can add a geojson file with the geometry of the country you want then customize the polygon to show just the country.

In the next link you will see a code example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-grass-ytuke?file=/index.html

Comment: That's clever. Thank you.

Only downside is to the exact shape of that particular country.